# Get child elements with their keys (jq)

Tags: json, key, jq, children

Using `jq`, I would like to get all the children of the root element and include their keys.

e.g. from this document:

```
{"foo": [1, 2, 3], "bar": [4, 5, 6]}
```

I would like to get:

```
{"foo": [1, 2, 3]}
{"bar": [4, 5, 6]}
```

Using variations on array indexing, I lose the keys:

```
echo '{"foo": [1, 2, 3], "bar": [4, 5, 6]}' | jq -c .[]
[1,2,3]
[4,5,6]
```

How can I get the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```
to_entries[] | [.] | from_entries
```

More prosaically:

```
keys_unsorted[] as $k | {($k): .[$k]}
```

Comment: These are both instructive. Thanks.

Comment: How's the view from Q1?

Comment: If I ever go I'll let you know. :)